# Библиотека cocoapod не импортируется в проект

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Всем привет!!!

Мне нужна помощь, я пробую создать свою библиотеку с UI
Создаю ее на основе Cocoapod

Файл со спекой библиотеки ( может тут что то стоит еще добавить ? )
[image: pod spec]

Библиотека прошла проверки перед публикацией
[image: pod lib lint]

Получилась ее закинуть в репозиторий
Есть возможность ее скачать через менеджер зависимостей

[image: pod file]
Когда делаю pod install то в консоли пишет что зависимость успешно установлена
Но когда пробую сделать import библиотек в проект то возникает ошибка, не может найти модуль

[image: import]

Если закинуть архив с библиотекой в проект ( не используя менеджер зависимостей, а давибавить файл с либой вручную ) то все работает

Мне бы хотелось, понять как сделать так чтобы библиотека смогла импортироваться ко мне в проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение моей проблемы, просто нужно было поправить source_files )

spec.source_files  = 'Skyline/**/*.{h,m,swift}'

Answer (score 1):

Кокоподс устроен следующим образом

1. Публичное облако имен. Когда указываете имя Пода, он уже зарегистрирован в общем облаке и ссылка подтягивается из общего облака.
2. Указанный репозиторий. Это работает так:

```
pod 'SPPermissions', :git => 'https://github.com/ivanvorobei/SPPermissions.git'
```

Во втором случае не нужна публикация пода в пространство имен. Чтобы сделать доступным без ссылки, введите команду `pod trunk push`. Если регистрация не нужна, укажите ссылку из примера.